# Duplicate Group Box

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

How can I Duplicate a Groupbox in C# window application ,
the group box contain 30 textbox and i need to duplicate it on a special event and I don't know the maximum number of needed groupbox

Comment: Create a user control that contains the group box and all of the textboxes, and then use that instead. (This is currently a comment because I don't think your question includes enough details for me to write a sufficiently comprehensive answer.)

Comment: (Cody Gray) What details you miss to provide you with it ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using winforms, possible solutions:

1. Put a groupbox on form, customize it, copy the generated code (from ..designer.cs file) and put it to a method. When you event occurs you just call the method that will create new control.
2. Using reflection create a new object of the same type and any writable property will get their values copied, use this method:

   ```
   private object CloneObject(object o)
   {
       Type t = o.GetType();
       PropertyInfo[] properties = t.GetProperties();


   Object p = t.InvokeMember("", System.Reflection.
       BindingFlags.CreateInstance, null, o, null);


   foreach (PropertyInfo pi in properties)
   {
       if (pi.CanWrite)
       {
           pi.SetValue(p, pi.GetValue(o, null), null);
       }
   }
   return p;


   }
   ```

Use it like:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
GroupBox g = (GroupBox)CloneObject(groupBox1);
}
```

Both methods are described [here](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/606031-how-clone-control)