# How can i use multiple instances of GroupBox in C# Forms?

Tags: c#, windows, forms, groupbox

I want to fill a form with multiple instances of the same `groupBox`, from top to bottom.
I couldn't find a way to clone or duplicate the groupBox.

[Duplicate Group Box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4544657/duplicate-group-box) did not work and neither did
[this](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/449050/Groupbox-duplicate-csharp).
I have seen a suggestion [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/891a47b9-c73a-44e7-a41f-0872f9efced4/groupbox-cloning?forum=vbgeneral) to solve this with a user control, but I have no idea how to do this.
A simple example would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: May show us some code? Right now we can only guess what happens

Comment: If you want to create a reusable group of controls then you should be creating a user control. You add one to your project in the same way you do a form - just select a different item type. You then design it the same way you would a form and add code in the same way you would a form. When you build your project, the new control will be added to the Toolbox and you can add instances to forms or other user controls as much as you like,

Comment: @John I have 4 groupBoxes with the same dimensions and the same controls, but the content is different (different text in the labels, for example), will I be able to dynamically copy one of these and use it multiple times in the form using a user control?

Comment: You can create instances of same groupbox, and then set location dynamically in your code

Comment: @Jakobson how? can you please give a simple code example?

Comment: Why would different content be a problem? Is it a problem to have different text in different TextBoxes? You define the control with appropriate properties, create as many instances as you want and set those properties to whatever values you want, just as you do for any other control.